# How to set beforeResolve navigation guard in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, nuxt.js

Is there a way to add beforeResolve navigation guard in nuxt.config.js?

My nuxt.config.js

```
module.exports {
    ...
    router: {
        beforeResolve(to, from, next) {
            if (this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn)
                 next('/resource')
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

But its never gets called!

I've been trying to achieve a redirection before the component is mounted based on the users logged in state on the vuex store.

Comment: Nuxt introduces [middleware](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#middleware) exaclty for such purpose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have 2 options for this. You can set a global rule via the middleware or in the respective page.

```
// middleware/route-guard.js
export default function ({ app }) {

    app.router.beforeResolve((to, from, next) => {
        if (app.store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
            next('/resource')
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });

}
```

---

```
// Nuxt Page Component
export default {
    beforeResolve (to, from, next) {
        if (this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
            next('/resource')
        } else {
            next();
        }
    }
  }
```