# Nuxt - How to set BeforeEnter guard for index page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

How to set Before Enter guard for index page in nuxt framework

i try some middlware setup but dose not work
please help me

Comment: Can you share some code explaining what you have tried and what are you trying to do ?

Comment: i try beforeEach in middleware but it dose not work

Comment: see here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61077912/6725944)

Comment: ok, and whats the problem now?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create middlewares according to Nuxt docs. https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-middleware/